# Redirect to Zoho matched Customer Record with Deluge function

Tags: zoho

I'm trying to embed a Zoho CRM by iframe into an application that knows only a phone number.

(Ramble: Originally I intended to call the Zoho api to lookup the Contact by phone number and redirect to or load the Contact's Zoho page - but the hosting app doesn't seem to support enough features to accommodate Zoho's OAuth2-only authentication - so I think I'm stuck with Zoho Deluge which I'm finding to be an ATROCIOUS language)

I'm hoping to GET navigate to this Zoho Function with the phone number as a parameter, have it find the unique match, and redirect to the customer details.

```
response = zoho.crm.searchRecords(
    "Contacts", 
    "", // no criteria - I hope the later parameter 
        // normalizes better than this would?
    1, // first page
    2, // of two max results - just to verify uniqueness
    "{ phone: '" + phoneNumber + "'}"); // Docs are terrible.  Is this the format? 
                                        // I also tried "phone:equal:..."

//if (1 < response.size()) { // script errors show up on nonsense line 
//  return "[Ambiguous]";    // numbers, but this seems to work until later
//}                          // lines are included - then errors point here

return response; // Works, but useless string output
return response.firstName; // "Invalid collection object found" - but not expected to work
return response.get(0); // 'TEXT' can not be cast to '[KEY-VALUE, TEXT, LIST]' for the function 'get'
return response.get('firstName'); // 'TEXT' can not be cast to '[KEY-VALUE, TEXT, LIST]' for the function 'get'
return response.get(0).firstName; // Improper Statement Error might be due to missing ';' at end of the line or incomplete expression

// openUrl( <string>, <window_type> ); // hoping to get here
```

I've also tried variations on returning from inside a for each element loop, no luck.

I THINK I've successfully found the user by phone number because I think I indeed get one match, but I can't verify it and I don't know how to derive the url of the customer detail page for the openUrl() call.  Do you know how to make progress on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *criteria* is malformed, and function *searchRecords* returns a list of maps.

To access the first element of al list you must use .get(0) and get an element of a map .get("First_Name")

The fields are malformed, you must get the API name of the field form crm.zoho.com->setup->API->API names->Contacts

You can use *info* to debug the response (info response;)

[Zoho CRM API Search records](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/search-records.html)

```
toReturn = "";
response = zoho.crm.searchRecords("Contacts", "Phone:equals:" + phoneNumber, 1, 2);
if (1 < response.size()) {
    toReturn = "[Ambiguous]";
} else if (0 == response.size()) {//error triggered if use get(0) of emty list
    toReturn = "[None]";
}else {
    toReturn = reponse.get(0).get("First_Name");
    openUrl("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/org[yourOrgID]/tab/Contacts/" + reponse.get(0).get("id"), "new window");
}
return toReturn;
```